# Query with subqueries returning more than I want

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, in-subquery, opensql

I have the following tables (those tables contain many records but for sake of this example I reduced the contents only to the records I want to operate on).

### Products

```
 product_id | product_name 
------------+--------------
          1 | PRODUCT
```

### Contracts

```
 contract_id | version | status | product_id 
-------------+---------+--------+------------
           2 |       1 | 30     |          1
           2 |       2 | 30     |          1
           2 |       3 | 30     |          1
           2 |       4 | 30     |          1
           2 |       5 | 30     |          1
           2 |       6 | 30     |          1
```

### People

```
 id | guid 
----+------
  3 |  123
  9 |  456
```

### Limits

```
 id | type 
----+------
  4 | 12
  5 | 14
```

### Link_table

```
 link_id | version | contract_id | object_type | function | obj_id 
---------+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------
       6 |       1 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      4
       7 |       2 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      5
       8 |       2 |           2 | BCBP        | BCA010   |    123
      10 |       3 |           2 | BCBP        | BCA010   |    456
```

Here is the DDL for the aforementioned tables...

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  product_id    integer PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name  varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE contracts (
  contract_id   integer,
  version   integer,
  status    varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  product_id    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products(product_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (contract_id, version)
);

CREATE TABLE link_table (
  link_id   integer,
  version   integer,
  contract_id   integer NOT NULL,
  object_type   varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  function  varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  obj_id    integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(link_id, version)
);

CREATE TABLE people (
  id    integer PRIMARY KEY,
  guid  integer,
  CONSTRAINT person_guid UNIQUE(guid)
);

CREATE TABLE limits (
  id    integer PRIMARY KEY,
  type  varchar(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Now... My task is to select the latest version of the value for field `type` in `limits` table for the latest version of the value `id` in the `people` table. The table `link_table` decides what the latest version is. This data need to be provided with fields `contract_id`, `status`, `product_name`.

I tried with the following query, unfortunately I receive two rows when I am supposed to receive only one with the latest value.

```
SELECT c.contract_id, status, product_name, type
  FROM
    contracts AS c
  INNER JOIN
    products AS p
  ON c.product_id = p.product_id
  INNER JOIN
    link_table AS per
  ON c.contract_id = per.contract_id
  INNER JOIN
    link_table AS ll
  ON per.contract_id = ll.contract_id
  INNER JOIN
    people AS peop
  ON per.obj_id = peop.guid
  INNER JOIN
    limits AS lim
  ON ll.obj_id = lim.id
  WHERE 
    peop.id = 3
    AND per.object_type = 'BCBP'
    AND per.function = 'BCA010'
    AND ll.object_type = 'XADL'
    AND ll.function = 'ADLTYP'
    AND ll.version IN ( SELECT max(version) FROM link_table WHERE link_id = ll.link_id)
    AND per.version IN ( SELECT max(version) FROM link_table WHERE link_id = per.link_id)
    AND c.version IN ( SELECT max(version) FROM contracts WHERE contract_id = c.contract_id );
```

The result I expect is

```
 contract_id | status | product_name | type 
-------------+--------+--------------+------
           2 | 30     | PRODUCT      | 12
```

However the actual outcome is

```
 contract_id | status | product_name | type 
-------------+--------+--------------+------
           2 | 30     | PRODUCT      | 12
           2 | 30     | PRODUCT      | 14
```

I have been struggling with this for over a day now. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? This example is done with PostgreSQL but the real problem needs to be solved with ABAP's OpenSQL so I cannot use `UNION`.

Here is some SQL to populate the tables.

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 'PRODUCT');
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 1, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 2, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 3, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 4, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 5, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (2, 6, '30', 1);
INSERT INTO people VALUES (3, 123);
INSERT INTO people VALUES (9, 456);
INSERT INTO limits VALUES (4, '12');
INSERT INTO limits VALUES (5, '14');
INSERT INTO link_table VALUES (6, 1, 2, 'XADL', 'ADLTYP', 4);
INSERT INTO link_table VALUES (7, 2, 2, 'XADL', 'ADLTYP', 5);
INSERT INTO link_table VALUES (8, 2, 2, 'BCBP', 'BCA010', 123);
INSERT INTO link_table VALUES (10, 3, 2, 'BCBP', 'BCA010', 456);
```

### EDIT

Looks like if the following records in `table_link`

```
 link_id | version | contract_id | object_type | function | obj_id 
---------+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------
       6 |       1 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      4
       7 |       2 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      5
```

were defined with the same `link_id` then my query would return exactly what I want.

```
 link_id | version | contract_id | object_type | function | obj_id 
---------+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------
       7 |       1 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      4
       7 |       2 |           2 | XADL        | ADLTYP   |      5
```

Unfortunately `link_id` is generated each time new in production even if there is a `version` in the composite key... Looks like I have to find another way or look for other fields in the link table that would help me.

Comment: Why do you have link_table twice in your query?

Comment: Because this table links many subtables to the contract table. If you could solve it with one join, then you are very welcome.

Comment: I think I'm missing something, you state `peop.id = 3` which is `objid = 123` but you result is `objid = 4` which doesn't even exists in people.

Comment: There is no obj_id column in my result, therefore I am not sure what you are asking about. :-)